# Pipe Password to Application When Asked

Tags: bash, pipe, password, curl, stdin

The following should be done in a bash script:

```
curl --digest --user schmijos https://bitbucket.org/u/p/get/tip.zip -o tip.zip
```

How can I automatically submit a password to *curl* when it asks for it? Since I don't want to see the password in any logfile, I **won't** do the following:

```
curl --digest --user schmijos:$password https://bitbucket.org/u/p/get/tip.zip -o tip.zip
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`empty`](http://empty.sourceforge.net/):

With the password safely stored (it's a way of saying...)

```
$ echo password > pwd-file
```

Start process with `empty`. (You would omit `-L log` in the real case.)

```
$ empty -f -i fifo1 -o fifo2 -L log curl -u user http://example.com
```

Send the contents of `pwd-file` to `empty`'s input pipe, which the process sees as both its `stdin` and `/dev/tty`.

```
$ empty -s -c -o fifo1 < pwd-file
```

This is what happened in the pseudo terminal:

```
$ cat log
<<<Enter host password for user 'user':>>>password
<<<
```

Comment: +1 - This seems to be a solid solution. But I would appreciate if the tools were built-in or available in a standard linux environment.

Answer (score 2):

Curl can read passwords from [`~/.netrc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc). Add a line like this to `~/.netrc`:

```
machine bitbucket.org login schmijos password swordfish
```

and run

```
curl --netrc --digest --user schmijos https://bitbucket.org/u/p/get/tip.zip -o tip
```

Comment: `~/.netrc` does not store encrypted passwords. Alternatives like [`crypt`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193643/netrc-netrc-alternative-to-curl) have to be used.

Comment: @JosuaSchmid If you encrypt the password, you'll have to enter the decryption password. You can put `.netrc` on an encrypted filesystem, that's an orthogonal concern. Did you want to get a password prompt if necessary? I didn't get that impression from your question.

Comment: You are right. I don't want the password to be stored (in any insecure way).

Comment: @JosuaSchmid Define insecure. If you don't want the password stored at all, why aren't you typing it when Curl prompts you to?

Comment: The script should be executed in background.

Comment: You can also use `--netrc-file` and process substitution (`<(...)`) to avoid a file with the contents of the password.