# feeding the password without any terminal window (stdout)

Tags: scripting, sudo, password

I have a command like this:

```
 echo "12345" | sudo abcde
```

where `12345` is supposed to be the root password and `abcde` a program or a command. I have a shortcut which runs this command. I have tested the command in a terminal window. It works, as the terminal output shows.

But will it work when it is run without terminal window, for instance by a shortcut or shortcut key? (where no output is shown)

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all...

Comment: You might want to use `empty` instead. It's discussed here: [Pipe Password to Application When Asked](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55882/pipe-password-to-application-when-asked/55888#55888)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should work (I don't have `sudo` to test it but even `su` works).

That's not how you do things, sudo is meant precisely for this situation - if you need that, configure it to not need a password for `abcde`.

Add this line

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/your/abcde
```

to `/etc/sudoers` and now `sudo` doesn't prompt the specified user for password for this particular command.

Never store passwords in plain text.

Comment: for me it seems impossible to configure `abcde` because it changes something in system networking. As I use it frequently, no other way remains.

Comment: I mean modify `/etc/sudoers` to include a line
`username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/your/abcde`
That's exactly how `sudo` is used. If you need password every time, use `su` and actually become root.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - yes the better method as orion is explaining is to configure a sudo rule such that you're just not prompted for a password at all or just for this specific command, `/path/to/your/abcde`. Piping the password as you're asking about is discouraged b/c a `ps` might leak your password if someone were to run one while you're performing this command. They would see the `echo password | cmd` in the output and you'd be screwed.

Comment: @orion - I'd add your example of sudo directly to your answer with a note saying to do this instead of echo pass.